# I got error while installation (TablePlus database management) in Linux

Tags: mysql, table-plus

Add TablePlus gpg key

```
wget -qO - http://deb.tableplus.com/apt.tableplus.com.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

got error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.